# How do I display post without comments using the Comments plug-in

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

Below is the code generated from facebook plugins page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
                <script>    (function (d, s, id) {
                        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="example.com" data-num-posts="1" data-width="200"></div>
```

How can I display only 1 post on my website but hide all the comments for that post?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an option for this with the Facebook comments plugin.  You could pull down all comments and render the post you wanted yourself via the graph api with this style url:
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments